# Rails action_mailer config not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I am trying to setup action_mailer with Rails 4.1.0 to send emails.

In my config/environments/{env}.rb, I have:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'domain.com',
  authentication:       'login',
  user_name:            'email@domain.com',
  password:             'pass',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

It's working fine in development, but in prod it's trying to connect to localhost.

```
m = Mail.new
m.delivery_method
=> #<Mail::SMTP:0xbd79fdac @settings={:address=>"localhost", :port=>25, :domain=>"localhost.localdomain", :user_name=>nil, :password=>nil, :authentication=>nil, :enable_starttls_auto=>true, :openssl_verify_mode=>nil, :ssl=>nil, :tls=>nil}>
```

But when I do "puts Rails.application.config.action_mailer" Im getting the correct config

```
{:raise_delivery_errors=>false, :default_url_options=>{:host=>"domain.com"}, :delivery_method=>:smtp, :smtp_settings=>{:address=>"smtp.mandrillapp.com", :port=>587, :domain=>"domain.com", :authentication=>"login", :user_name=>"email@domain.com", :password=>"password", :enable_starttls_auto=>true}, :assets_dir=>"xxx", :javascripts_dir=>"xxx", :stylesheets_dir=>"xxx", :asset_host=>nil, :relative_url_root=>nil}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Mail.new.delivery_method returns non-rails mail delivery method. Just do `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` if you want your action mailer info.

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment. ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings is showing the correct informations, but mail = mail.new; ...; mail.deliver is still trying to connect to localhost

Comment: probably a confirmation account from madrillapp?, something like what happens with Sendgrid

Comment: nop, mail is trying to connect to localhost on port 25.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot I had this config in my development.rb

```
Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method Rails.configuration.action_mailer.delivery_method, Rails.configuration.action_mailer.smtp_settings
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The Mail gem won't use your ActionMailer config by default. ActionMailer uses Mail but those configuration settings will only apply if you send mail via ActionMailer.

If it's working in your dev mode, then you certainly have configured the Mail gem separately in your development.rb environment file, or in an environment specific initializer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `host` option for the `default_url_options` hash on the `production.rb` file, like so:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['HOST_DEFAULT_URL'], 
                                           only_path: false }
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: This is already set config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'domain.com' }